# Make Entire Touchpad responsive

Tags: 15.04, mouse, touchpad

My touchpad has no buttons but can be pressed down like a button everywhere. In the lower area (approximately as high as buttons would be), the touchpad isn't responsive if I haven't started touching it somewhere else.

Ubuntu also makes that when I press the touchpad down on the right half of this lower area, a right-click is executed, while everywhere else a left-click is executed. So I'm pretty sure it's made this way intentionally. However, I don't like it.

Because I used an Ubuntu 14.04 live system, I know that it isn't this way in Ubuntu 14.04. But I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. Can I make my touchpad responsive everywhere in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

First, find out the settings of which device you need to change. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) will help you.

The is was `11` in my case. Then just execute

```
xinput --set-prop 11 "Synaptics Soft Button Areas" 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

And change `11` to the id of your touchpad. That's it. It works instantly.

Unfortunately, the settings reset when you restart your computer. So put this command into your startup applications.